# Xcode from Unity: "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am getting a "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". As far as I understand, it is telling me that I am missing some framework.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Glrd.png). I have added all the frameworks manually:
:

[image]

After cleaning and trying again, the error still persists but it complains about another framework!

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QD2R.png). I have also set the 'Search Path' in 'Build Settings' to recursive:

[image]

Every time I try and built it on my ipad I get the same error but complaining about a different framework despite [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Glrd.png)&[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QD2R.png). Has come across this?

I am working on Xcode Version 7.3.1

The error screenshot:
[image]

Directort Structure:

[image]

UPDATED Search Path:
[image]

Comment: where is the error screenshot ?

Comment: Without a more precise error message, there is nothing anyone can do to help.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick responses! The error message is added.

Comment: OK so it cannot find the `qtsensors` framework/library.  Now you have to go and find it and if you do find it, ensure it's the right CPU architecture.  Start by finding it.

Comment: @Droppy, I have found it and replaced it in the framework (again), not its telling me that "Framework not found for qtpositioning" ... I think the archicteture is right(its for mac..), but how could I check?

Comment: Rinse and repeat then, I guess.

Comment: can you show the directory structure how are you adding it ?

Comment: Directory structure is added to the question :)

Comment: I also just tried a build where I moved the framework files into the first 'Frameworks' folder (in case it was sitting to deep in folders for Xcode to find it)...still, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: you are building for the device right ? and not the simulator

Comment: Yes.     On the upper left-side I see, Unity IPhone > *NameOfMyIpad*

Comment: make sure the framework search paths do not change when you re add a new framework. i think the issue is adding a framework makes the path linking change and therefore the previously working ones get broken

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116553/discussion-between-bonnieb-and-shubhank).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, **removing** the all the problematic frameworks (those starting with QT) allowed me to build the app and didn't cause any noticeable issues. Its not a particularly satisfying solution, but it worked ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that Can You check Project Target>Buil Phases>Link Binary with librarys  in more than one time it is define or podfile is define multiple time some frameworks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean as well. I have made sure there are no framework duplicates and the framework I am getting an error on is also there.

Comment: Can you add pod file into your project?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue w/ my project. I install my pods via CocoaPods, once I open up the workspace project created, I import the modules to the file. At first there will be an error, but once you Build the project, it will sweep the error. That's how I fixed my issue.